# Classes and models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

Is  creating classes and creating models are same.
For example if I had to make a product class, so I have to make a product model for same?

Comment: Do you mean if every class in the `models` folder needs to have a database table? No that is not the case. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I need to import a csv file in this class and read that csv file and create articles with it and I have a article model with article table in db.

Comment: It would be perfectly fine to have, for example, a `CSVImporter` class (pure Ruby) that has not database table (does not inherit from the `ApplicationRecord`) but instead does all the stuff that needs to happen to import CSV files into a `Product` model. I am still not sure if I understand your actual question. Can you please elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have an post blog that have a db table of title and content now I want to add a class that will import and export the csv file for me.If import it will read the data from the file and display post and if export it will export the post data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you need a Product Class you create a Product Model. Once you created Product Model, Product Class is available.

Comment: I have to import csv in product and after importing I have to put the data of csv file in another table . How to implement this.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers your question. Not ask a different question..

Answer (score 0):

Model is a little bit complex entity than just a class. Model in rails is representation of Active Record. Here its contents:

> Active Record gives us several mechanisms, the most important being the ability to:
> Represent models and their data.
> Represent associations between these models.
> Represent inheritance hierarchies through related models.
> Validate models before they get persisted to the database.
> Perform database operations in an object-oriented fashion.

In order to create order, you will need to create a table (rails uses migrations for this case), and model class in this example `product`. You can use rails generators to achieve this, the following will create both *model* and *migration*

`bin/rails generate model Product name:string description:text`

further reading.
[Active Record](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_basics.html#what-is-active-record-questionmark)
[Model Generators](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_migrations.html#model-generators)